# How to detect if flash installed from C# for Firefox?

Tags: c#, flash, server-side

Is there a way to check if flash is installed in Firefox from C# code on the server? For instance when the client browser is IE, you can check 
Request.Headers["accept"].Contains ("application/x-shockwave-flash")
but a Firefox request doesnt contain the same header.

Comment: From an application running on the client, or from an ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you've tagged this as "server-side" and talk about the client's machine, then you may well be disappointed.

The only way to check this is with code running on the host you're checking (i.e. the client) - of course, you could do this and transmit the answer to the server (to store in the session, for example)

Edit: It's also worth remembering that any headers you receive (or rely on receiving) may be removed by intermediate proxies, or just plain lying (could be a bot)

Comment: And then there are cases of flash installed, but disabled (e.g. Firefox's FlashBlock extension).

Comment: And then the problem with remembering this, what if they change to a browser without Flash after visiting with one that has Flash?

Comment: I was assuming that the session handling was standard behaviour (I.e. auto-created for a request without a cookie; cookies expiring after first of: set time period or browser exit)